# jQuery Datepicker - Run Function After Month or Year are Selected

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex, jquery-ui-datepicker

For context, I'm using the jQuery datepicker plugin for Oracle Apex.

Right now I have a datepicker where I need to "materialize" the select inputs - aka hide the existing Month/Year dropdowns and create my own so I can apply Material CSS styles to them.

I have a function that works on page load; however, upon selecting a month or year, the html structure reverts back to the original structure.

I have tried using `onChangeMonthYear` and `onSelect`. `onChangeMonthYear` doesn't even seem to fire for me, whereas `onSelect` works but only on the date selection.

I guess there's probably a better question of is this the right way to do it, running the materializing function post select of a month or is there a better way to target it, maybe even prevent it from changing at all after click.

**For context, the browser default styles:**

[image]

**And the styles I need to apply**

[image]

I used the JavaScript, minus some class names, found here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp.

Also, some of the styles are a bit off right now because I can't get it to stick long enough to get it looking better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There should be a hidden input that holds the date value. Maybe use "change" function on that to fire your materialize function?

Comment: @FunkDoc it reverts on click of the month dropdown. So if I open the month, select a month, it closes the month list and reverts before I even have an opportunity to change the date

Comment: Oh, I see. Then how about $(".ui-datepicker-month option").click(function(){//do materialize}); ?

Comment: @FunkDoc I tried that, for some reason it's not firing on click of the month

Comment: I found https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/wra3pcsv/15/ which is quite literally what I need to do, but after the datepicker has already been initialized